# Studio: Non-functioning wifi drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, ubuntu-studio

I just installed Ubuntu Studio, it's all working fine except my wifi. In "Software & Updates" I have installed the proprietary BCM4313 802.11/b/g/n driver but no wireless internet options appear. I can only access internet if I am using ethernet. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have your answer: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-a-broadcom-wireless-driver)

Then, this questions is duplicated.